# How to add textSize modification to custom ArrayAdapter<OwnClass> in android?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I want to create a ToDo-List app and I needed a custom `ArrayAdapter<OwnClass>` to display the user input.

The class I am using to store the user input is:

```
public class ListElement {

private String title;
private String description;
private PriorityEnum priority;

ListElement (String title, String description, PriorityEnum pe) {
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.priority = pe;
}

public String getDescription() {return description;}

public String getTitle() {return title;}

public PriorityEnum getPriority() {return priority;}

}
```

Where `PriorityEnum` can either be *high, medium or low*.

I made the current, **working** ListAdapter with the help of a [tutorial](https://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/). This is the modified version I am using:

```
public class ListElementArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListElement> {

// declaring our ArrayList of items
private ArrayList<ListElement> objects;

/* here we must override the constructor for ArrayAdapter
* the only variable we care about now is ArrayList<Item> objects,
* because it is the list of objects we want to display.
*/
public ListElementArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<ListElement> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.objects = objects;
}

/*
 * we are overriding the getView method here - this is what defines how each
 * list item will look.
 */
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    // assign the view we are converting to a local variable
    View v = convertView;

    // first check to see if the view is null. if so, we have to inflate it.
    // to inflate it basically means to render, or show, the view.
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    /*
     * Recall that the variable position is sent in as an argument to this method.
     * The variable simply refers to the position of the current object in the list. (The ArrayAdapter
     * iterates through the list we sent it)
     *
     * Therefore, it refers to the current Item object.
     */
    ListElement i = objects.get(position);

    if (i != null) {

        // This is how you obtain a reference to the TextViews.
        // These TextViews are created in the XML files we defined.

        TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
        TextView ttd = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptextdata);
        TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
        TextView btd = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.desctext);

        // check to see if each individual textview is null.
        // if not, assign some text!
        if (tt != null){
            tt.setText("Title: ");
        }
        if (ttd != null){
            ttd.setText(i.getTitle());
        }
        if (bt != null){
            bt.setText("Description: ");
        }
        if (btd != null){
            btd.setText(i.getDescription());
        }
    }

    // the view must be returned to our activity
    return v;
}
}
```

(Comments are from the tutorial)

It depicts the List correctly, but the text size is too small.

**I already tried:**

1. creating a custom xml file
   -> Problem: my professor wants the user to be able to change the size
2. searched the internet and found `getView()` returning a `TextView` Element
   -> Problem: I don't know how to apply this to the working `ArrayAdapter` and I am too bad to write a new one by myself..

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can have a look on the items xml "list_item"

Comment: Thank you, but what do you mean?